# Calculate cumulative distance for route using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

The route shown below represents the mobile signal strength for a route thats been driven. The red dots are poor signal, yellow dots fair signal etc. The data is stored in a postgres table and is geo-coded using lat & long.

Its required to calculate the total distance per category i.e. what distance was driven where signal is poor, fair etc.

Is there a mechanism in PostGIS to bin the segments and sum them?

[image]

### EDIT (supplied data as requested):

The data currently is currently as follows. There aren't any GIS types.

| ID | Lat | Long | Time | Signal Strength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| long | double | double | string | string |
| 1 | 4.13883879 | 11.52922145 | 15:04:00.500 | Poor |
| 1 | 4.13873610 | 11.52914528 | 15:04:02.500 | Poor |
| 1 | 4.13819539 | 11.52914528 | 15:04:04.500 | Fair |
| 1 | 4.13793128 | 11.52870903 | 15:04:06.500 | Fair |
| 1 | 4.13755825 | 11.52861072 | 15:04:08.500 | Poor |

Comment: You are referring to 'segments' of a 'route', but all there is are 'dots'....please be more specific about your actual data, it's geometry type, SRID and attributes; are your segments LineStrings, having the 'signal strength' as column? Or are you solely working with these Points above?

Comment: And what about the drive between two points in different categories?

Comment: @geozelot I've added clarifications about data in the post. Currently there are no GIS datatypes, all I have are the Points.